# php regex to find repeated character not working

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Basic php regex to find repeated character not working..

```
$subject = 'rrrr';
var_dump(preg_match("/([a-zA-Z])\1{2,}$/i", $subject));
var_dump(preg_match("/(\w)\1{2,}$/i", $subject));
```

same seem to be working here : https://regex101.com/r/OCAwi0/2

Comment: And when you use `'/([a-z])\1{2,}$/i'` it will. Magic? No, [**string literals**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double). :)

Comment: its working now

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, example in link : https://3v4l.org/9MFvm

```
<?php

$regex = '#([a-zA-z ])\1{2,}$#';
$string = 'rrrr';
preg_match($regex, $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: Do you know what `[A-z]` matches? Letters only? No, [have a look here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29771926/3832970).

Comment: That isn't the question Wiktor. And it isn't my regex.

Comment: Anyway, the question is a duplicate bordering on an off-topic question type.